# Include Input In All Form Submissions

Tags: html, forms

Similar to how an input outside of a form element can be including in submission using the form= attribute. Is it possible to include an input in every form submission without using javascript?

```
<input type="hidden" form="*" name="include-all" value="id1234"> //This is an example and is not working html
```

I am using a scope id server side to manage browser tabs and this id needs to be passed with each form submission. Its redundant having to include the hidden element in each and every form container.

I've considered including the id in the querystring but this destroys bookmarking and adds complexity to my request handler. Though it may be my best option...

Comment: Can you use sessions on the server side?

Comment: Yes I am using sessions...the session will store the scope id and that way a single session can manage multiple browser tabs each with their own unique set of values.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Why are you trying to manage browser tabs?

Comment: I described in the question. I am trying to use the session to store multiple sets of values based on a specific id so that when a user has multiple browser tabs open each of them has access to their own portion of the session. I need to pass the scope id to the browser so it can be submitted with each form post and therefore the server knows where to fetch that view's values within the session. Make sense?

The reason I want to manage browser tabs is so that users can have a unique version of the application open across multiple tabs.

Comment: You might want to decide whether you want to support that type of behavior.  As you can see, it is adding significant complexity to your code.  How will you reconcile conflicts between tabs?

Comment: I haven't considered the weight of the feature fully yet, but that doesn't change my curiosity as to whether an input value can be included in all forms. That functionality would have some other benefits for me too.

Comment: If you spend enough time, you can do it.  Don't bother.  Work on more important features of your application.

Answer (score 0):

Does the `button` you are using have a value? In my application, to get an id, I just set it as the value of the submit button (`<button>`) and call a $_POST request on the button's `name` attribute.

Comment: In some cases such a button only forms the button's value is already spoken for. I'm trying to add an input in the header or at the top of the body (though the position doesn't matter) and have it's value automatically sent with each post.

Comment: So you do not want to manually add your `id` attribute to every post?

Comment: That is what I am trying to avoid.